# Unable to build Kotlin multi-platform SDK because of missing of tools.jar, on macOS

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a kotlin multiplatform, SDK where i am trying to do gradle build and i get the error below.

Latest version of Java I have is 17(by java=17.0.8-amzn), I am using SDKMan for java versions,

Task :clientcore:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':clientcore:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home contains a valid JDK installation.

I already tried to copy the home directory of java virtual machines to internet plugins
Nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you need a different JDK version to run your project locally? In my case, I needed JDK 8, but the existing version installed on my local machine was JDK 14, so I needed to change the version.

If your situation is similar to mine, execute the following commands:

```
$ brew tap AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk
$ brew install --cask adoptopenjdk8
```

After that, check the version and path of the installed JDK using this command:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V | grep jdk
```

Next, run this command as well. You need to run this command because the embedded JDK installed directly on your local system takes precedence over the JDK installed through Homebrew.

Finally, I resolved it by adding the path corresponding to "AdoptOpenJDK 8," which is **/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home**, to either **.zshrc** or **.bash_profile**.

```
# ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zshrc

export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Good Luck.

Comment: it doesnt solve it, i tried it already